# Using rdtsc + rdtscp across context switch

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, context-switch, rdtsc

I am trying to write a program to measure context switch. I have gone through this [Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf) about rdtsc + rdtscp instructions.

Now, I want to use these time-stamp instructions across context switch. I have the general skeleton as follows:

```
// init two pipes P1, P2
fork();

set_affinity();              // same core

// parent's code:
    cpuid + rdtsc            // start timer
    write(timer to P1);

    read(timer from P2);     // blocks parent if timer value not written
    rdtscp + cpuid           // stop timer, get difference

// child's code:
    read(timer from P1);     // blocks child if timer value not written
    rdtscp + cpuid           // stop timer, get difference

    cpuid + rdtsc            // start timer
    write(timer to P2);
```

There are a few problem I am seeing with this code. Assuming the timer operations are correct,

If the OS chooses to context switch to some entirely different process (not the child or parent), it won't work.

This code will also include the time taken by the read() and write() system calls.

Ignoring these issues, is it a valid use of rdtsc + rdtscp instructions?

```
I know writing a kernel module and disabling preemption/interrupts is a better way
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before, and it seems to be a valid way of measuring context switch time. Whenever doing timing of something this fine-grained, scheduling unpredictability is always going to come into play; usually you deal with that by measuring thousands of times and looking for figures like the minimum, media, or mean time interval. You can make scheduling less of an issue by running both processes with real-time `SCHED_FIFO` priority. If you want to know actual *switching* time (on a single cpu core) you need to bind both processes to a single cpu with affinity settings. If you just want to know latency for one process being able to respond to the output of another, letting them run on different cpus is fine.

Another issue to keep in mind is that voluntary and involuntary context switches, and switches starting from user-space versus from kernel-space have different costs. Yours is likely to be voluntary. Measuring involuntary is harder and requires poking at shared memory from busy loops, or similar.

Comment: I am running it with the `time -v` command to check for voluntary/involuntary switches. So far, the involuntary switches are very minimum (< 0.1%). The context switch time comes to be about 30K cycles/12.5usec.

Answer (score 1):

I used a similar timing code, except I have the parent loop 1000000 times, and time the whole loop in both the parent and child. The code is attached. Then I modified it to time the individual context switches, as in you pseudo-code, summed the 1000000 individual times and got good agreement with my original code. So either way seems to work, given the caveats already mentioned.

The thing I find interesting is that the context switching time is more than doubled when `sched_setaffinity()` is used to set the parent and child to run on separate cpus. Why does that affect the time in that way? Is the pipe faster between processes running on same cpu?

rdtscp.h:

```
static inline unsigned long rdtscp_start(void) {
  unsigned long var;
  unsigned int hi, lo;

  __asm volatile ("cpuid\n\t"
          "rdtsc\n\t" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi)
          :: "%rbx", "%rcx");

  var = ((unsigned long)hi << 32) | lo;
  return (var);
}

static inline unsigned long rdtscp_end(void) {
  unsigned long var;
  unsigned int hi, lo;

  __asm volatile ("rdtscp\n\t"
          "mov %%edx, %1\n\t"
          "mov %%eax, %0\n\t"
          "cpuid\n\t"  : "=r" (lo), "=r" (hi)
          :: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");

  var = ((unsigned long)hi << 32) | lo;
  return (var);
  }

/*see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/embedded/training/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.html
 */
```

cntxtSwtchr.c:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "rdtscp.h"

int main() {
  int pipe1[2], pipe2[2];
  pipe(pipe1) || pipe(pipe2);
  cpu_set_t set;
  CPU_ZERO(&set);

  clock_t tick, tock;

  int fork_rtn;
  if ((fork_rtn = fork()) < 0)
    exit(1);

  if (fork_rtn == 0) {  // Child
    close(pipe1[1]);
    close(pipe2[0]);

    CPU_SET(1, &set);
    sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(set), &set);

    tick = clock();
    unsigned long tsc_start = rdtscp_start();
    int i;
    while (read(pipe1[0], &i, 4)) 
      write(pipe2[1], &i, 4);
    printf("child tsc_ticks: %lu\n", rdtscp_end() - tsc_start);
    tock = clock();
    clock_t ticks = tock - tick;
    double dt = (double)ticks / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Elapsed child cpu time: %gs.\n", dt); 

    close(pipe1[0]);
    close(pipe2[1]);
    exit(0);

  } else {              // Parent
    close(pipe1[0]);
    close(pipe2[1]);

    CPU_SET(1, &set);
    sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(set), &set);

    int idx, lim = 1000000;
    int i_rtnd;
    tick = clock();
    unsigned long tsc_start = rdtscp_start();
    for (idx = 0; idx < lim; ++idx) {
      write(pipe1[1], &idx, 4);
      read(pipe2[0], &i_rtnd, 4);
      if (i_rtnd != idx) 
    break;
    }
    printf("parent tsc_ticks: %lu\n", rdtscp_end() - tsc_start);
    tock = clock();
    clock_t ticks = tock - tick;
    double dt = (double)ticks / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Elapsed parent cpu time: %gs, %gs/switch.\n", dt, dt / lim); 
    if (idx == lim)
      printf("Parent reached end of processing loop.\n");
    else
      printf("Parent failed to reach end of processing loop.\n");

    close(pipe1[1]);
    close(pipe2[0]);
    exit(0);
  }

}
```